# what different and why need "this.initialize.apply" in constructor function

Tags: javascript, constructor, this, prototype, apply

I read some code or library that uses the code snippet , like

```
function Example(){
    this.initialize.apply(this , arguments);
};

Example.prototype.initialize = function(){
    this.a = false;
    ...
}
```

I know what is happen by the code 
but I find out the alternative way could do the same thing

```
function newExample(){
    this.a = true;
    this.arg1 = arguments[0]
}

const obj = new newExample('arg1');
```

both ways give the same effect , 
So , why people do not use the second way , it seems easier.
or just I misunderstanding the meaning of the snippet at the first way ??

I found some explanation on internet ,
but still confusing , could somebody tells me?
thanks.

Comment: perhaps they want a separate `initialize` function rather than initialize in the constructor? Perhaps they don't know what they're doing? without full code it's anyone's guess

Comment: maybe you are right , thanks for your comment.